# Messing up ;w; (Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File ("c:\\temp_Name\\FileName.in"));) code. (BaseClass)

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

So the objective of the code that is shown here is to make it so that I can create a generic class (Shell) for reading/processing files that also includes a NumberFormat object as well as StringTokenizer and Scanner objects.

Here is my code.....

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

 public class BaseClass {
   public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException 
   {
       NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance ();
       fmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(3); //may need to change value
       fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(3); //may need to change value

       Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File ("c:\\temp_Name\\FileName.in"));
       int maxIndx = -1; // -1 so when we increment below, the first index is 0 
       String text [] = new String[1000]; // to be safe, declare more that we need while
       (sf.hasNext())
       {
           maxIndx++;
           text[maxIndx] = sf.nextLine();
           //System.out.println(text[maxIndx]); // remove rem for testing
       }
       // maxIndx is now the highest index of text []. Equals -1 if no text lines
       sf.close(); // We opened the file above, so close it when finished
       // System.exit (0); // Use this just for testing
       for (int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++)
       {
           StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (text[j] ); 
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(text[j]);
           System.out.println(text[j]);
       }


   }
```

}

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    c:\temp_Name\FileName.in (The system cannot find the path specified) 
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) 
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) 
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656) 
at BaseClass.main(BaseClass.java:14) 
Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds) –
```

Comment: IT DISPLAYS THIS ERROR

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\temp_Name\FileName.in (The system cannot find the path specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
 at BaseClass.main(BaseClass.java:14)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Apparently the file you're referencing at that path doesn't exist. I'm not running Windows so I can't prove it, but maybe try capitalizing the **C** drive.

Comment: Please browse to the filepath `C:\temp_Name\\`. Do you see your file there? Is it exactly the same name?

Comment: @Mena: Your instinct may be correct, but Windows isn't a case-sensitive platform.

Comment: Ok thank you Jeroen Vannevel, I found the file, but now it is displaying another error, on line 27, the String Tokenizer is not compiling correctly. Here is the error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>   (StringTokenizer.java:236)
 at BaseClass.main(BaseClass.java:27)
   Java Result: 1
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @user2757303 that is another question unrelated to this question which should be closed

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure FileName.in really exist. But I suggest you use Java 7 Path instead of File.